# Why write the log output code after SpringApplication.run() , it will not be executed, while other code can be executed?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, logback

I create a demo program use SpringInitializr。

jdk8
maven 3.6.3
windows11

**import**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.10</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>demo</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**main application**

```
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("log output before SpringApplication.run");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        System.out.println("after SpringApplication.run first System.out.println");
        log.info("log output after SpringApplication.run");
        System.out.println("System.out.println end");
    }
}
```

**result**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5AM5.jpg)

```
03:23:26.850 [main] INFO com.example.demo.Application - log output before             SpringApplication.run

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.5.10)

after SpringApplication.run first System.out.println
System.out.println end
```

Why the console does not output log.info(), but can output  System.out.println()?
I tried to change the logback version, or use log4j，has the same result

**Thank you very much for helping me**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you set `logging level` to `WARN` or `ERROR` in your `application.properties` file (or other logger-configuration file).

For example, in `application.properties`

```
logging.level.root=WARN
```

By default it is `INFO` - that is why you see the printed log before Spring application starts.

Then Spring application starts and changes level to one of the below INFO: ERROR or WARN - according to configuration you have provided.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me.As you said, I checked and modified the configuration file to solve the problem.

Comment: I am glad I could help :) Can you mark the answer as the correct one?